# Impersonalization - domain specific user without password - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to programmatically impersonate domain specific user with assigned groups without a password and without SeTcbPrivilege in ASP.NET MVC application?

This feature will be used as "See the application as specific user".

Comment: See blog post http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/user-impersonation-with-asp-net-identity-2/

Comment: I need Windows domain specific user without a password.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is possible to impersonate a domain user without password.

There are two way:

1. put user account and password in web.config
2. programming impersonate in code

you may refer to below MSDN article for detail

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306158/how-to-implement-impersonation-in-an-asp.net-application

Comment: I need a Windows domain specific user without a password.